# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'exponents_processing_batches.Sequence_train'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

My sequence_train class is defined as:

```
class Sequence_train(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_data, y_data, batch_size=10, n_variables=8):
        self.x_data = x_data
        self.y_data = y_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_variables = n_variables

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x_data)/float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, item):

        batch_x = self.x_data.iloc[item*self.batch_size:(item+1)*self.batch_size,:]
        batch_y = self.y_data[item * self.batch_size:(item + 1) * self.batch_size]
        k = []

        for idx in batch_x.index:

            k.append(list(filter(lambda v: v == v, batch_x.loc[idx])))

        j = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(k, padding='post', value=0)
        j = j.reshape([self.batch_size, int(j.shape[-1]/self.n_variables), self.n_variables])

        return np.asarray(j),np.asarray(batch_y)
```

And when i try to fit the x_train in  `model.fit_generator(generator=x_train, epochs=50, verbose=2)`
I also tried without the generator.
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'exponents_processing_batches.Sequence_train'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused, because you are not guaranteeing that x_train,y_train,y_test and y_test data is a np.array(). So go take a look at those variables and check if they are on the expected dtype or in a array. Here i a sample on how.

```
train_x = np.asarray(train_x).astype('int32')
```

Comment: I actually solved it by doing 
'return tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(j,dtype="float32"),tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(batch_y,dtype="float32")'

Comment: Well that is basically what i said, just check if your variable are at the same dtype or in the same python object(list ) etc